# SQL query to determine that this is mssql DB and not other DB's

Tags: sql-server

How to write a query to just determine that it is mssql ?
and fail on other db's

How can i verify for example something like this :

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL_Server_Version' where 'SQL_Server_Version' like '%Microsft%';
```

This donst work

Comment: How can you not know what DBMS you are connecting to? I suppose you could something like select @@version.

Comment: Depending on the connection type you often have to specify a provider type. Do that with a specific provider code and you should expect an error if there is a miss-match. With OLE you would use `Provider=SQLOLEDB`. With ODBC you would use `Driver={SQL Server}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select case when @@Version like 'Microsoft SQL Server%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or this:

```
select version
from (
    select @@Version as version
) v
where version like 'Microsoft Sql Server%'
```

Comment: how can i make it not return row when the answer is false? 
if i remove the else im getting NULL

Comment: @user63898 put this same logic in a `WHERE` clause instead